# Things to consider when choosing a sailing club

Tags: sailing, boats

Apart from the obvious like price and location(s) what should I look for when choosing a sailing club?
Some of the things are difficult to assess, tips on assessment are welcome.

I want this question to be the base of a comprehensive list of items to look for when choosing a sailing club.

To be clear, I'm talking about a club that rents sailboats, not ones that just coordinate between sailors.

Comment: The bar is a very important factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to David's answer, I'd also include

- training courses
- membership in points racing league
- RYA accreditation, at least in the UK
- adult and child friendly/capable (is it targeted at children or adults or both)
- facilities, e.g. anti fouling, over winter storage, maintenance etc
- location - is it somewhere you want to sail from?

Comment: What do you mean by "adult friendly"?

Comment: @David - updated.

Answer (score 5):

- Variety and number of boats.
- Added price for fuel/weekends.
- Level of upkeep (how to check that?)
- Members to boats ratio, to know how easy it is to find an available boat.
- Special rules/limits (of people on the boats, maximum rentals per month, night rentals, etc...).
- Club activities.
- Membership cancellation/freeze policies.